# Auto-computed column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

Is it possible for a column in to be auto-calculated by SQL Server 2012 itself?

For example: I have three columns `START_DATE`, `END_DATE` and `DURATION`.

I want to get the duration by doing this :

```
DURATION = END_DATE - START_DATE
```

So I get the duration in number of days.

Is it possible for SQL Server 2012 to do it automatically on record creation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, sure - just define `Duration` to be a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD Duration AS DATEDIFF(DAY, START_DATE, END_DATE) PERSISTED
```

and off you go. Now `Duration` will always show the difference (in days) between these two other columns. The value computed will be stored along side your other column values, if you use the `PERSISTED` keyword. This column will be updated if any of the two "dependent" columns changes, too.

**Update:** if you want to get the difference between a date and today, you can use

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD Duration AS DATEDIFF(DAY, START_DATE, GETDATE())
```

but unfortunately, since the `GETDATE()` function is non-deterministic (after all - it's return value changes every time you call it), you cannot use the `PERSISTED` keyword. This means: every time you access the column (ask for its value), the calculation will be done again.

Comment: Thank you very much. And how, for example, If I wanted today's date, how do you perform the same calculation instead of END_DATE , i.e. `today's date - start_date` ?

Comment: What I tried is this: `ALTER TABLE dbo.users
ADD age AS DATEDIFF(YEAR, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), date_of_birth) PERSISTED` but I get  this error: ` Computed column 'age' in table 'users' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.`

Comment: @Brian: using `GETDATE()` is the problem - that's non-deterministic, so you cannot persist the value. If you **must** use `GETDATE()`, then you must leave out the `PERSISTED` keyword and the value will be calculated every time you access the column

Comment: So is there any alternative to `GETDATE()` so that I could get the date automatically with `PERSISTED`?

Comment: @Brian: no, unfortunately not. Since the current date (with the time portion included) is **always** non-deterministic, you really can't do this....

Comment: @Brian no, but do you absolutely need it to be persisted? It doesn't make sense to persist this value, since it changes every day.

Comment: @Brian also you know that taking `DATEDIFF(YEAR` is not a reliable way to calculate an age, right? It essentially treats everyone's birthday as January 1st.

Answer (score 1):

In your Table Design, enter any of these in `(Formula)` under Computed Column Specification for your required result.

**For Date Difference:**

```
CAST(job_end - job_start) AS TIME(0))
```

**For Time Duration:**

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(END_DATE-START_DATE),120),12,8)
```

Similarly you can compute for `Second`, `Minute`, `Hour`, `Month`, `Year` differences.

**Syntax for using `DATEDIFF`:**

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

**For your Reference:**

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS SecondDifference
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS MinuteDifference
DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS HourDifference
DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS DayDifference
DATEDIFF(WEEK, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS WeekDifference
```